# Toggle ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to toggle class "category-active" to an active category tab using ng-class and ng-click. Nothing seems to happen when I click the tabs. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">

<div class="wrap"  ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>Bakery Menu</h1>

  <div class="content">

      <div class="categories">
       <ul>
        <li ng-class="{'category-active' : active}">
          <a href="" ng-click="active = !active; categoryList('all')">All</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{'category-active' : active}" ng-repeat="menu in menus">
          <a href="" ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu" href=""  ng-click="active = !active; categoryList(key)">{{menus}}
          </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('bakeryMenuApp')
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {  
  dataService.getMenus(function(response) { 
      $scope.menus = response.data.menus;
      $scope.category = 'all';
      $scope.categoryList = function(value) {
        $scope.category = value;
      }  
  });
})
```

JSON:

```
{  
"menus":[  
  {  
     "brownies":[  
        {  
           "name":"Baker's Choice Bars Assortment",
           "price":"45",
           "description":"A beautiful and delicious assortment of Magnolia Bakery’s double fudge brownies, chocolate chunk blondies and magic cookie bars.",
           "image_url":"https://pantograph0.goldbely.com/s364/uploads/product_image/image/8346/bakers-choice-bars-assortment.1ddd25a1f59a89a1de2d0583dab50000.jpg",
           "is_vegan":false,
           "is_gluten_free":false
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "cakes":[  
        {  
           "name":"Raseberry Lemon Cake",
           "price":"50",
           "description":"Vanilla crème fraîche cake layered with raspberry Swiss meringue buttercream and lemon curd filling, covered with raspberry buttercream.",
           "image_url":"http://www.empirecake.com/_main_site/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Rasberry_Lemon_01_final_drkr-600.jpg",
           "is_vegan":false,
           "is_gluten_free":false
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: And your script is? Looks like you should replace `'category-active' : active` with smth like `activeCategory === 'all'/key`, then use some setter to adjust the value of `activeCategory` accordingly.

Comment: Where is your controller? And that your `active = !active` logic really belongs in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it had to do with ng-repeat and scope. I changed the scope and used directive to solve it.

```
   <ul>
    <li ng-init="selected === 'all'" ng-class="{'category-active':selected==='all'}">
      <a sibling href="" ng-click="selected = 'all'; categoryList('all')">All</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-init="active = false"  ng-repeat="menu in menus">
      <a sibling href="" ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu" href="" ng-click="categoryList(key)">{{key}}
      </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('bakeryMenuApp')
.directive('sibling', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                element.parent().parent().children().removeClass('category-active');
                element.parent().addClass('category-active');
            })
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic seems wrong. Try this:

```
   <li ng-class="{'category-active':selected==='all'}">
      <a href="" ng-click="selected='all'; categoryList('all')">All</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'category-active':selected===menu}" ng-repeat="menu in menus">
      <a href="" ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu" href=""  ng-click="selected=menu; categoryList(key)">{{menus}}
      </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: it works for 'all', but not for the rest of the menu items.

Comment: @JaeeunLee: can u check now?